# Logstash and looking up additional data from a relational table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, logstash, kibana

I have mobile app log data being posted daily (eventually it will be a data stream). I am looking at different solutions for processing this log data and providing analytics. I am considering using logstash/elasticsearch/kibana combination, but we have additional data on our users stored in a redshift database. So in addition to the mobile data, I would like to pull in additional data from redshift about the user at the time of interaction with mobile app.

However, I've read in some places that doing an actual database query through logstash isn't feasible, but you can use a dictionary file to do a lookup of each user.

I have two questions regarding this approach

1. Is there a limit to have large this lookup file can be? Mine would be < 500K records so I'd imagine it would be fine?
2. Can the process of making the the lookup file from redshift tables be fully automated (ideally though aws services) - i.e. each night the lookup table is refreshed and posted to logstash, and then used for breakouts in Kibana

The way we're currently doing it is processing a daily jason file with a lambda function, posting it to s3 and then reading it into a redshift table. This data is then processed into sessions and joined up with other tables to generate the final dataset to be used for visualization. This is currently done in Tableau but we are exploring other options (such as quicksight, or possibly the ELK stack)

Just trying to figure out what solution is going to be scalable to clickstream data and will be the most useful down the line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

logstash 7 has a [jdbc_streaming](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-jdbc_streaming.html) filter plugin for dynamically adding stuff to your events, as well as the [jdbc_static](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-jdbc_static.html) filter for static stuff.

As you found, you can also use the [translate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html) filter.  The man page says they've tested "very large" datasets up to 100,000 entries, so your dataset may require some testing.  The good part about this filter is that it will reload the data when it detects a change, so you can publish the data on your own schedule (e.g. cron) without restarting logstash.  Be on the lookout for events that don't get the translated value, which might be a sign that your publishing frequency should be updated.

Comment: The translate filter is a good idea for this use case, but if the dictionary file gets too big it could block logstash pipeline while it is starting or reload, if this happens, you could check the `memcached` filter, which will query a memcached server with your key-value data and is very fast and simple to implement.

Comment: The doc days that the translate dictionary is loaded in a separate thread, so it shouldn't block regular event processing.

Comment: It depends on the size, the separated thread minimises the impact, but on my case the dictionary was really too big (10M+ lines) for it to make any difference.

Comment: Since they discuss "very large" datasets at 100K lines, I would assume 10M would be more extreme.  It should still be loaded in a separate thread and not block the pipeline, however.